# How can I pass two separate queries to a callback function at the end of a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, callback, promise

I am currently trying to pass two queries to a callback function at the end of my promise chain. I have tried to pass an object and array to the last .then() callback but am never able to retrieve the values of the arguments I pass in. Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I should do or read to understand how I can fix my problem? I have also attached two screenshots of the logger.

```
mysql.createConnection({
    host     : ' ',
    port     : ' ',
    user     : ' ',
    password : ' ',
    database : ' '
}).then(function(conn) {

    var mysqlDate = new moment(new Date().setDate(12)).add(-4,'h').toDate().toISOString();
    mysqlDate = mysqlDate.replace(/[T]/g, ' ').replace(/[Z]/g, '');
    mysqlDate = mysqlDate.substring(0, mysqlDate.length - 4);
    console.log(`Current date: ${mysqlDate}`);
    var query = `SELECT * FROM PredictedTolls WHERE Entry = '${entry}' AND _Exit = '${_exit}' AND DateTime <= '${mysqlDate}' ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1`;
    console.log(`Current Time Query: ${query}`);
    var result = conn.query(query);

    var mysqlLater = new moment(new Date().setDate(12)).add(-4, 'h').add(30, 'm').toDate().toISOString();
    mysqlLater = mysqlLater.replace(/[T]/g, ' ').replace(/[Z]/g, '');
    mysqlLater = mysqlLater.substring(0, mysqlLater.length - 4);
    console.log(`Later date: ${mysqlLater}`);
    var queryLater = `SELECT * FROM PredictedTolls WHERE Entry = '${entry}' AND _Exit = '${_exit}' AND DateTime <= '${mysqlLater}' ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1`;
    console.log(`Future Time Query: ${queryLater}`);
    var resultLater = conn.query(queryLater);

    console.log(`Result Later: ${resultLater}`);
    conn.end();
    return [result, resultLater];
}).then(function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    var dateTime = rows[0].DateTime;
    var toll = rows[0].PredictedToll;

    console.log(`Best time: ${dateTime}`);

    options.speechText = `The best time to leave is <say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>${dateTime}</say-as> with a toll of <say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>${toll}</say-as>. `;
    options.endSession = true;
    context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
});
```

[Log Info 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA9T6.png)
[Log Info 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cfyt.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning an Array of promises, not a `Promise`.

All you have to do is return `Promise.all([result, resultLater]);`, that takes an array of promises as argument, and of course returns a `Promise` that will resolve when all the internal promises have been resolved.

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have
>   resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
mysql.createConnection({
    host     : ' ',
    port     : ' ',
    user     : ' ',
    password : ' ',
    database : ' '
}).then(function(conn) {

    /* ... */
    return Promise.all([result, resultLater]);
}).then(function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    // rows will have [result, resultLater] resolved values
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and helping me out!